# Error after installing dnf on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dnf

Installed `dnf` according to [these instructions](http://www.tecmint.com/dnf-commands-for-fedora-rpm-package-management/):

```
yum install epel-release -y
yum install dnf
```

after that `dnf --version` works fine but `dnf repolist` or anything else gives:

```
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64  668 kB/s | 9.4 MB     00:14
Failed to open: /var/cache/dnf/x86_64/7/x86_64/7/epel/repodata/e8...19-updateinfo.xml.bz2.
```

and running `dnf clean all` doesn't solve this.

There seems to be [bug report](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=9339) about this, without a solution.

Is there some way to get `dnf` working on CentOS 7?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `epel-release` (using `yum remove epel-release`) and then run `dnf repolist`?

Comment: I did not see anywhere that you had to do that, but after remove it looks like it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure why this is, but it looks like the epel-release repository (from where you install `dnf`) is not compatible with `dnf` itself. After installing `dnf`, first remove this using `yum`:

```
yum remove epel-release
```

and after that:

```
dnf repolist
dnf list installed
```

etc. worked (at least on my CentOS 7 system).

Answer (score 5):

The issue may have to do with the installed version of libsolv not supporting bzip2 compression. Like me, you may not have the most recent version being installed because setting priorities in the repo config files.

> Failed to open: /var/cache/dnf/x86_64/7/x86_64/7/epel/...xml.**bz2**

See bug report [1258416](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1258416).

> libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7 has been pushed to the Fedora EPEL 7 stable repository. If
>   problems still persist, please make note of it in this bug report.

The libsolv installed from the CentOS `base` repository is 0.6.11-1.el7, but the one in `epel` is 0.6.14-1.el7.

```
yum --showduplicates --disablerepo=base list libsolv
Installed Packages
libsolv.x86_64          0.6.11-1.el7          @base
Available Packages
libsolv.x86_64          0.6.14-1.el7          epel
```

**Solution**

Install libsolv from the `epel` repository.

```
yum --disablerepo=base install libsolv-0.6.14-1.el7
```

---

**Edit: 2016-06-17**

As seen in the comments, this is still an active bug with the package repositories. This is because of `libsolv` being marked as "retired" in the EPEL without an explanation ([Theodor van Nahl](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1258416#c16)). Dennis M. Pöpperl [points](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1258416#c15) out that RPMs of versions that had seemed to have been working in CentOS and RHEL are available [here](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=704417) in the Fedora build system.

Comment: Kevin's answer was spot on, but I couldn't find the 'new' libsolv in epel, but I did find a 0.6.20 version in epel-testing, which solved my issue ... thanks, Kevin!

Comment: @Bob3396, now both libsolv-0.6.14 and 0.6.20 seem to have been removed from the EPEL repository. I noted this in the bug report.

Comment: The lack of a libsolv version in EPEL 7 can been seen [here](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/libsolv).